# Is there an update to set commas to existing integers/decimals used as currencies in a table?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench, number-formatting, alter-table

Data already exists, but since it refers to large amounts, it's not so readable without commas.

I've read this is the function:

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/LVoEC.png)

but how do I make a sentence to modify the existing data in a table?

Comment: "this is the function" - what does that mean? Why not add these commas in your application?

Comment: Do not add commas in the data.  Numeric data should always be stored using numeric types.  Instead, add commas in your client or in a select of the data.

Comment: Adding commas to stored data means they are no longer numbers.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this should be done in your frontend application. The database should only store data in it's raw format. That way you have the possibility to change the formating depending on the users location for example, since not all countries use "." and "," the same way in numbers.

If you just need it while you are developing your querys and not for the end-user, you could search, if your sql-client has an option to format the output, but it is probably not done in your sql-query.